How to change the appearance of Rviz
I am new in Rviz. I attached a screenshot of the Rviz window here.

Can anyone let me know how can I make the appearance of the turtlebot bigger than the existing appearance?
Secondly, how can I change the floor color to white?
Thank you.

try moving the camera closer to the bot

Where is the camera? Which icon you are asking about?

To make the appearance of turtlebot bigger, click the turtlebot and simply scroll up your mouse. To navigate the camera left, right, and up, you can press the middle click and hover in the direction you want.
To make the floor color white:
You can change the background color to white and the grid color to black.

